# Set hours in 00:00:00 in react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

How set from Thu Sep 24 2020 **14:59:41** GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time) on Thu Sep 24 2020 **00:00:00** GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time) ?

Comment: A *date* picker shouldn't generate a time component in the first place. Where did `14:59` come from?

Comment: For initial date i use new Date().

Answer (score 3):

new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)) - good work.

Comment: Thank you, its working as expected.